# Preventing re-paint in Google Chrome via CSS/JS/etc

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to cause Google Chrome to prevent painting... as in, to keep the page exactly the same, no animations or content changes.

---

The reason I ask is because I have [created an extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gemmknjnneiojfjelmgappppbaneikda) for people who find it difficult to read webpages when things are animating/flashing/changing/etc.

It currently works by taking a screenshot and layering it over the page (position absolute, with a high value z-index).

But because [captureVisibleTab](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-captureVisibleTab) cannot capture the whole page ([issue 45209](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=45209)), the screenshot needs to be re-created every time the user scrolls the page.

However the change in iOS 8 Safari to [not pause printing while scrolling](http://developer.telerik.com/featured/scroll-event-change-ios-8-big-deal/) got me thinking there may be another way around this by trying to emulate the pre iOS 8 behaviour (something I preferred, as Reader View does not always work, or stop animated gifs).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot stop the execution thread, its browser who decides it.
However to prevent CPU Cycles What chrome does is, Pauses the javascript execution thread when window is blurred. But since you are showing captured with higher z-index you window will still be active.

One possible way :

```
Disable the script for that url when the page is loaded.
```

You might miss the dynamic content but as you asked "no animations or content changes". Any dom or style manipulations by javscript causes repaint of the page. Disabling it might be one solution. However not pretty sure about how to stop css animations.

I have also seen extensions that can capture full webpage image or pdf. you can capture the full page and show them irrelevant of whatever changing in the background

Comment: Good point about the execution thread (I just wondered if there was anything that could effect it, e.g. if it thought it was a background/blurred tab)... and good thinking about disabling scripting  (presumably though chrome.contentSettings.javascript)... but disabling JS probably wouldn't stop animated gifs or CSS animations.

Comment: As to the full page screen capture, I believe that is only possible by scrolling around the page and calling captureVisibleTab multiple times (slow/buggy), or using a NPAPI extension (deprecated), or sending the URL off to a remote server to render via something like webkit2png (not good from a security/privacy/volume point of view)... see [issue 45209](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=45209).

Comment: @CraigFrancis You can disable the frame animation for GIFs.

Comment: interesting, will need to look at that... but at the same time it will also need to stop Flash/Silverlight type extensions as well (which is starting to sound messy).

Comment: @CraigFrancis What about the resetting the animation css rules for every element then blocking scripts on that page

Comment: That could work, but my concern is that when someone wants to read something, they request the page to stop changing (via the extension), it stops the JS (chrome.contentSettings.javascript), animated gifs (disable the frame animation), css animations (reset rules), Flash/Silverlight, etc... then restore them all when they are done reading and want to continue to use the website... it could work, and I suspect is the only solution, but it is prone to bugs (some other extensions have tried this, but they don't quite get it right either).